# Assigning New Object to a Generic Array Index

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm POSITIVE that my title for this topic is not appropriate.  Let me explain.  The purpose of this is to duplicate a "Profile" application, where I have a profile and so would you.  We both have our own followers and in this example, we both follow each other.  What this method is needed to return is a cross reference based on whom you follow that I do not.  I need this method to return to me a recommended `Profile` object that I do not already have in my array.  Right now I'm having a difficult time with one line of code within a particular method.

One of my classes is a `Set` class that implements a `SetInterface` (provided by my professor) and also my `Profile` class that implements a `ProfileInterface` which was also provided.  In my code for the `Profile` class, I have the following object:  `private Set<ProfileInterface> followBag = new Set<ProfileInterface>();`  which utilizes the Array bag methods from my `Set` class with the `ProfileInterface` methods I've made.

Here is the method (not complete but can't move further without my problem being explained):

```
public ProfileInterface recommend(){
    Set<ProfileInterface> recommended;
    ProfileInterface thisProfile = new Profile();
    for(int index = 0; index < followBag.getCurrentSize(); index++){
        Set<ProfileInterface> follows = followBag[index].toArray();
        for(int followedFollowers = 0; followedFollowers < follows.getCurrentSize(); followedFollowers++) {
            if()
            //if Profile's do not match, set recommended == the Profile
        }
    }
    return recommended;
}
```

The purpose of this method is to parse through an array (`Profile` as this example) and then take each of those sub-`Profiles` and do a similar action.  The reason for this much like "Twitter", "Facebook", or "LinkedIn"; where each `Profile` has followers.  This method is meant to look through the highest `Profile`s follows and see if those sub`Profile`s have any followers that aren't being followed by the highest one.  This method is then meant to return that `Profile` as a recommended one to be followed.  This is my first dealing with `Array Bag` data structures, as well as with generics.  Through "IntelliJ", I'm receiving errors with the line `Set<ProfileInterface> follows = followBag[index].toArray();`.  Let me explain the reason for this line.  What I'm trying to do is take "my" profile (in this example), and see who I'm following.  For each followed profile (or `followBag[index]`) I wish to see if `followBag[index][index] == followBag[index]` and continue to parse the array to see if it matches.  But, due to my confusion with generics and array bag data structures, I'm having major difficulties figuring this out.

I'd like to do the following:

```
//for all of my followers
    //look at a particular followed profile
         //look at all of that profile's followers
              //if they match one of my followers, do nothing
              //else
              //if they don't match, recommend that profile
         //return that profile or null
```

My problem is that I do not know how to appropriately create an object of a `Profile` type that will allow me to return this object
   (in my method above, the line `Set<ProfileInterface> follows = followBag[index].toArray();`)

I'm trying to make an index of my `Profile` set to an object that can later be compared where my difficulties are.  I'd really appreciate any insight into how this should be done.

Much appreciated for all help and Cheers!

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what the types of all your variables are.  But of course you can't assign an array into a `Set`, because they're different types.  If you have an array, and you want to create a `Set` with all the elements of the array, try `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a))` where `a` is an array.  If this isn't what you want, then I'll need to spend more time studying your question, because I'm finding it hard to follow.

Comment: @ajb Understandable.  Let me quickly explain.  `Set` is a class that implements an interface.  `Set` is meant to be an Array Bag class for an assignment I have for class.  I have done some research and `hash` has been a lot of the answers I've seen, but I haven't learned that yet.  So using that will probably not be suitable.  Within my `Set` is a method `toArray()` that will transfer a given generic to an array of that type.  I hope that information helps as much as I appreciate your efforts to help me understand this topic.

Comment: The question uses confusing phrasing, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Whoa, wait a minute. Are you saying that you've created some class that you've named `Set` that implements some other interface?  That's extremely confusing, because Java already has an _interface_ named `Set`, and without any other explanation, everybody will assume that's what `Set<ProfileInterface>` means.  And your `toArray()` method doesn't return an array, but returns an object of your `Set` class?  Even more confusing.  Sorry, but I think you'll have to post a lot more code before anyone can figure out what you're trying to do.  I sure can't.

Comment: We were provided a `SetInterface` which we needed to implement into a `Set` class.  That interface contains methods which are meant to be used as an array bag for my `Profile` class (which also implements certain methods of a `ProfileInterface` that was provided.  My `Profile` class contains an assignment as:  `private Set<ProfileInterface> followBag = new Set<ProfileInterface>();` which I use within the `Profile` class.  In this method, I need to check the `Profiles` in my `Set` bag and see if any of their followed `Profiles` match mine.  If not, I want to grab them.  There is my issue.

Comment: I've updated my original thread to include more specifics concerning what I'm trying to accomplish.  I hope that this helps to explain what I am trying to do with the one line of code.

Comment: It would be more clear, if you would provide code of class, that contains `recommend` method. I don't understand what for `ProfileInterface thisProfile = new Profile();` line needed, if we never use it in the body of method. How does `ProfileInterface` look lik? And why do you return just one recommended profile? What if  you'll find several?

Comment: "Set<ProfileInterface> followBag" if in this case Set is data type created by you then how can you do followBag[index] on it?

Comment: I think your profile class represents a person's profile and the Set is a class that contains list of follower of the profile.If this assumption is correct then I think your Set class must contain an array as an instance member.Also getCurrentSize() method that you have used must return size of this array.What you can do is to implement a method getArray() or getFollowers() which returns this array. For ex. followBag.getFollowers()[index].This shall work in  your case.

Comment: The `[index]` syntax is only for Java arrays (and any class you define isn't a Java array, even though you might think of it as some kind of "array").  If you want an indexing function, you'll need to add a `get(int index)` method to your `Set`, similar to how Java defines one for `List`.  Even better would be to define an iterator, but you might not know how to do that.

Comment: @professionallyme86 Your assumptions are correct and I like your approach.  For everyone's knowledge, I was completely unaware to @ajb had said about Java already containing a `Set` interface within the API.  As I mentioned, we were provided two interfaces which we needed to create the code for.  Then we need to create a client that will perform the task working with a list of `Profiles`, as well as other tasks utilizing these two classes:  `Set` and `Profile`.  My `Set` class contains most of the methods mentioned in the Java Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
Set<ProfileInterface> follows = followBag[index].toArray();
```

you're trying to use `Set` as `Array`. But you can't. 
Java will not allow, because `Set` and `Array` are different classes, and `Set` does not support `[]` syntax. 
That is why you get error. For use`followBag` as `Array` you have to convert it:

```
ProfileInterface[] profileArray = followBag.toArray(new ProfileInterface[followBag.size()]);

for(int i=0; i<profileArray.length; i++){
   ProfileInterface profile = profileArray[i];
   //do what you would like to do with array item
}
```

I believe, in your case, you don't need assign `Set` object to generic `Array` at all. Because you can enumerate `Set` as is.

```
public class Profile {

    private Set<ProfileInterface> followBag = new HashSet<Profile>();

    ...

    public Set<ProfileInterface> recommended(){
        Set<ProfileInterface> recommendSet = new HashSet<ProfileInterface>();
        for(Profile follower : followBag){
            for(Profile subfollower : follower.followBag){
                if(!this.followBag.contains(subfollower)){
                    recommendSet.add(subfollower);
                }
            }
        }
        return recommendSet;
    }    
}
```

I also added possibility of returning list of recommended profiles, because there is may be several.

Comment: I should have submitted my unique `Set` class that we had to create within my original post.  This versions of `Set` class has an `toArray()` method that allows me to make an array copy of a given `Set`.  What I was trying to do was to make an array copy of the `followBag`, which each index is already another array.  But I can understand your point somewhat.  As for `HashSet`, I've never learned this yet in my Data Structures class.  And I too thought about returning a list of unfollowed profiles, but I'm only supposed to return one `Profile` in this method.